# PHP + PayPal: make payment by PayPal without screen login

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have a new question. This is my context:

I want to make my own API REST, where I can call this method with information about my product as parameters. My backend method do the typical purchased process but it doesn't show the PayPal screen which show information about my product, just do the process directly and I receive an answer. Is it possible?

I'm using the PayPal SDK for PHP, and looking for at Google I just have gotten that the PayPal page shows, but I'm new in this. Your answer will be so good!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is very possible. There are plenty of tutorials online for building your own REST service, and within your service methods you can hit other APIs or do anything you need to do.

Your service can parse the results from the 3rd party service you're hitting (you could hit 10 different services if you wanted to) and then you would generated your own basic response which includes a collection of all that data back to whatever client hits your service.